# (System)Verilog: signal is x or 1 depending on placement of concurrent blocks in the code?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm basically aware that the Verilog scheduler is inherently indeterminate, but I really don't understand why that's the case with the following code (I've simulated both cases with Icarus and Incisive on EDA Playground). The differences between the `TB_A` and `TB_B` is in the order of the `initial` and `always` blocks.

Case A:

```
module TB_A ();

reg nrst;
reg signal;

initial
    nrst = 1'b0; 

always @(negedge nrst)
    signal = 1'b1;

initial
    #10 $display("value is: %b",signal);

endmodule
```

Case B:

```
module TB_B ();

reg nrst;
reg signal;


always @(negedge nrst)
    signal = 1'b1;

initial
    nrst = 1'b0; 

initial
    #10 $display("value is: %b",signal);

endmodule
```

I would expect that at T=0 the transition on `nrst` occurs and inevitably triggers the `always` block, putting `signal` at 1. This happens in Case B but not in Case A, where is displayed the value x for `signal`. In other words I wouldn't expect indeterminacy in this case, but evidently I'm missing something. Switching to SystemVerilog doesn't change anything.

Comment: I'm a little surprised that it's interpreting an X -> 0 transition as "negedge". I wouldn't say it's indeterminate either if it's taking actions on blocks based on their order in the program. The real lesson is to avoid at all costs depending on this kind of behaviour.

Comment: The outcome for both should be the same as the outcome for case A. No idea why case B is giving you the output it is. The reason why in A you get signal being 'x' is because it doesn't know whether to clock signal or not - an 'x' to 0 transition might be a negedge (1 to 0), or it might not be (0 to 0), so signal will become unknown 'x' even if it wasn't previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People misunderstand the simulation behavior of `always` blocks. It does not execute at every negedge. It is a process just like an `initial` block that executes procedural statements. It the same as if you wrote

```
initial begin
    nrst = 1'b0; 
    end
initial begin
  @(negedge nrst) // this means suspend the process and wait for a negedge
    signal = 1'b1;
 @(negedge nrst)
    signal = 1'b1;
  ... // repeats infinitely for an always block
   end
```

This is a race condition because the order that `initial` blocks start their processes determine if the assignment to `nrst` in one process is seen by the other process that suspends waiting for a negedge transition. A NBA assignment to `nrst` as well as moving the assignment after time 0 would solve this race.

Comment: It's clear now. I was searching for other references and found [this one](http://sutherland-hdl.com/pdfs/verilog_2001_ref_guide.pdf) from Sutherland himself, who comments on "sensitivity list" at the bottom of page 24.

Comment: Yes, the _sensitivity list_  is a low-level coding pattern that synthesis tool recognize to implement hardware.